# how can i make a web dynamic project with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, reactjs, user-interface

I made a react UI and a web service with spring boot and gradle . I have a make a web dynamic project with UI as reactjs and backend as a WAR file. Can someone tell me how to convert my normal react project into a web dynamic project using react?

Answer (score 0):

Got to manage FE project via java using npm build through [frontend maven plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin).

Or there are some custom oob attempts [like this](https://github.com/shekhargulati/spring-boot-react-maven-starter) but I'd prefer previous attempt.